# How to clean up all stored passwords and cache on a work Macbook before returning the computer?

Tags: google-chrome

I have a Macbook at home and a Macbook from work. I use the Google Chrome with a user profile of my personal account as well on the work computer, just so as to easily transfer some information when needed (such as a phone number I need to call this afternoon, or some UNIX command I want to save forever, not just on the work computer).

When I return the Macbook from work to the computer, is going to Chrome's Settings, and Advanced, Reset Settings all it needs to clear everything out?

Do I need to do it for each of the user profile? (personal, and work)?

Comment: How secure do you need this to be? Is Filevault enabled? Is it MDM-managed or 'free'?

Comment: that I actually haven't checked... the computer was shipped from the company to me and I never bother to check

Comment: If it's completely unmanaged - follow [What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065) & send them a blank machine. If it's managed, you might not be able to, in which case your IT department must take responsibility for wiping it.

Comment: @Tetsujin oh interesting... I was just able to press CMD-R and then erase the hard drive after I clear all Google Chrome stuff, removed the WiFi password, etc. But I didn't know in some case I can't even erase the hard drive if it is either Filevault enabled or MDM-managed? There is no way to force an erase of the hard drive?  So for example, if a teenager uses the Macbook and the parents want it back and want to erase or re-format the hard drive, the teenager could have enabled those features and the parents cannot even erase or format the hard drive?

Comment: Well… that was step 7. The first 6 get much harder if you already wiped it. Filevault we will now never know [so we will also never know if the wipe was secure], but if you could wipe it, it wasn't managed.

Comment: A home user cannot set up MDM [easily]. A lot of the rest is dependant on Mac model & whether Secure Boot is on or off. If Secure Boot is set, then no-one other than the person with the password for that can do anything, not even an admin account.